# Issue with loading bar in JS

Tags: javascript, file, upload, progress

I've got this code to run a progress bar to match the progress of the upload of a file in JS, it was working fine but when I added a line of code and then delete it because I changed my mind about it it just suddenly stopped working.

I've tried to CTRL+Z to prior the adding of that line I mentioned before but it's still not working

Here is the code for the handling of the progress bar:

```
function uploadFile(){
    var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file", file);

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);

    ajax.open("POST", "upload.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}

function progressHandler(event) {
    alert((event.loaded/event.total)*100)
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    document.getElementById("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Uploading status: " + Math.round(percent)+"%";
}
```

And here's my progress bar  in HTML:

```
<progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width: 20%; margin-top: 10px;"></progress>
    <p id="status" style="font-size: 13px; margin: 5px; margin-top: 7px"></p>
```

Can anyone help me? I can't wrap my mind aroud what's wrong

Comment: Update: I've tried on Windows (Chrome), Android (Opera) and Linux Ubuntu (Firefox) and I've noticed it does not work only on linux. I don't know if it's a browser problem since I've tried on three different browser but still I can't understand what's going on since it was working fine on all three OS until a few minutes ago

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: Could the issue be that the file is being uploaded synchronously? Try:
`ajax.open("POST", "upload.php", true);`

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get an error? What is your expectation and how is your code failing to fulfill it?